# Бейдж «Сторонник» вручён более одного раза

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, знаки

> [image: Бейдж получен трижды за 6 минут]

Проверяя сегодня свои бейджи с интересом обнаружил, что Сторонник, который, судя по описанию, даётся за первый голос "За" на сайте, был получен мной [трижды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter?userid=14756), все три раза - 31.03.2015, в период с 5:59 до 6:05.

Comment: Любопытно, это во время переезда скрипт три раза вас посчитал.

Comment: @Nofate да, я так и предположил, в чате.